# Why is laravel's updateOrCreate creating new records instead of updating?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Code**

```
Entry::updateOrCreate([
    'intern_id'=>$intern['id'],
    'created_at'=>Carbon::parse($input['date'])
    ],[
    'company_id'=>$intern['supervisor']['company']['id'],
    'content'=>$input['text']
]);
```

I'm using this code to try updating/creating a new record. It's suppose to matche `intern_id` and `create_at` column first. If found, then it creates a new one. However, it seems like it is always creating a new one and when it creates a new one, the `company_id` and `intern_id` column is set to 0 instead of the original value.

Note: `intern_id` or `created_at` are not PK columns.
Note2: `created_at` is a Date type, not DateTime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code

```
Entry::updateOrCreate(['intern_id'=>$intern['id']],
    [
        'created_at'=>Carbon::parse($input['date']),
        'company_id'=> $intern['supervisor']['company']['id'],
        'content'=>$input['text']
    ]);
```

I believe this will work.

`updateOrCreate()` function of Model Abstract Class takes 2 parameters, but your parameter passing is breaking.

```
/**
     * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return static
     */
    public static function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = array())
    {
        $instance = static::firstOrNew($attributes);

        $instance->fill($values)->save();

        return $instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Entry::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'intern_id' => $intern['id'],
    ],
    [
        'created_at' => Carbon::parse($input['date'])
            'company_id' => $intern['supervisor']['company']['id'],
        'content' => $input['text']
    ]
);
```

because first argument array searched for first time 
found one line with date and second line found other date deferent
    -----------

// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.

```
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where it was only creating a record but it wasn't being updated in the event that the record exists.

The issue is that to allow for the mass assignment on the update you need to add the fields to be updated as fillable in your model.

In your **Entry** model you can have something close to this :

```
   protected $fillable = [

           'company_id',
           'content',

           ];
```

I hope this helps in sorting out the issue.